# What bug could this be?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I found a bunch of bugs, approximately 2-3mm in my kitchen, most of them dead and with a throughout search i found a bunch of them living in my gluten-free flour and on some other products like fried batter peels (idk if this is correct, excuse my english) I live in Germany and found them during winter time.
I dont know what those are and google doesnt really help me.
Does anyone know? [image: Bug]

[image: Bug2]

[image: Bug3]

Comment: Please include better pictures. Also pictures of the "top" side of the insect would be beneficial. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

It's difficult to be certain, but this could be a drugstore beetle, *Stegobium paniceum*. They commonly infest kitchens where they feed on dry plant matter. In addition to eating various grains and spices, they are capable of feeding on material from plants like tobacco that are toxic to most other insects.